# Executing a script inside an ASAR archive

Tags: node.js, asar

I am attempting to run a script that is archived inside an ASAR file like so:

```
var spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;

var t = spawn('node', ['./bundle.asar/main.js'], {});

t.on('data', function(data){      
  console.log(data.toString());
});

t.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
t.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

FYI the above script is situated outside the ASAR archive.
However, all I get is the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MyUser\tests\asar-test\bundle.asar\main.js'
```

The official docs on this particular issue are nonexistent.
Is there some way to either read the ASAR file or require a script inside it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity, the answer to this is to `require` your .js file like so:

```
var spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;
var myScript = require('./bundle.asar/main.js');

var t = spawn('node', [myScript], {});

t.on('data', function(data){      
  console.log(data.toString());
});

t.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
t.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Hope this helps.