# Execute a node.js script in packaged electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

In electron packaged app, I am trying to execute a server file from a node_modules dependency.
From the main process, I'm trying something like:

```
var cp = require('child_process')
cp.execFile('node', path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/my-module/server.js'))
```

I see the server is launched as expected when launching my app from my local command-line, but not when packaged as asar.
What is the right way to achieve that?

Notes:
I have looked into https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-packaging/#executing-binaries-inside-asar-archive:

> There are Node APIs that can execute binaries like child_process.exec, child_process.spawn and child_process.execFile, but only execFile is supported to execute binaries inside asar archive.

Also, saw this SO answer:
[Executing a script inside an ASAR archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41085174/executing-a-script-inside-an-asar-archive) which says I need to `require` my script - however, I think it's wrong. This actually spawns this script within the same process (once required) and not when performing `execFile`.

Comment: If you packaged your app with electron-builder, there's an `extraResources` option in the `build` section of your package.json that you can use to copy certain files into the resources/app directory, outside of the asar. If you bundle your app with the node.js binary, you can use child process to spawn the scripts in the extra resources directory.

Comment: @Bailey Thank you so much!!! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to bundle node with electron.
Just make sure your 'node_modules/my-module/server.js' is packaged in asar and use

```
cp.fork(path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/my-module/server.js'))
```

or

```
cp.fork(require.resolve('my-module/server.js'))
```

it should work just fine.

This way electron will use bundled node, add transparent asar support to it and run script from asar archive.

If you `cp.execFile('node'...` you will use outside node, that doesn't support asar.

Comment: I checked that process.cwd() is not the app dir (...Resources/app.asar) so require.resolve does not work on my end.

It will only work when I skipped the asar packing, at the time process.cwd() === (...Resources/app).

Acoording to the docs it's the correct behavior I guess? (https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/asar-archives#working-directory-can-not-be-set-to-directories-in-archive)